# How to copy resource in new variable and destroy old resource?

Tags: php, resources, gd

Given the following code:

```
imagecopyresized($new_image, $product, $dst_x, $dst_y, $src_x, $src_y, $dst_width, $dst_height, $src_width, $src_height);

imagedestroy($product);
$product = $new_image;
imagedestroy($new_image);
```

The last line destroys `$product`, not just `$new_image`, as if `$product` is some sort of pointer to `$new_image`. Why does this happen and how can I effectively create a copy of *$new_image* within *$product* and then destroy the `$new_image` resource?

Comment: First of all, you should read up the [manual on resources](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.resource.php). Secondly, `$new_image` is a reference to the image. When you copy it to another variable, you copy the reference, not the image. On the other hand, I'd like to question a pointless and exhaustive operation of copying a resource and removing the older one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why this happens:

PHP uses copy-on-write memory management, i.e., you will not allocate new space in memory for the variable --> just point to the same memory location.

How to avoid this:

```
imagecopyresized($new_image, $product, $dst_x, $dst_y, $src_x, $src_y, $dst_width, $dst_height, $src_width, $src_height);

imagedestroy($product);
$product = clone $new_image;
imagedestroy($new_image);
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.cloning.php

About copy-on-write:
http://www.research.ibm.com/trl/people/mich/pub/200901_popl2009phpsem.pdf

Comment: True, but this is the wrong fact for the answer. The image resource reference is indeed a reference, destroying the image nullifies all references to the image - as simple as that.

Answer (score 1):

`$product` **is** an identifier for the same resource as `$new_image`. Use `$product = clone $new_image;` to get a copy of the image resource. You will then be able to call `imagedestroy($new_image)` without destroying `$product`.